# How to improve accuracy score for this regression problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am working with the student performance dataset from UCI. I want to predict the final result of a student based on the features given.

I first tried using two main and highly correlated features G1 and G2 that are grades of two exams. I used LinearRegression algorithm and got an accuracy of 0.4 or less.

Then I tried feature engineering on all the features that are objects in dataframe and still the accuracy is same.

How can I improve accuracy score ?

[My code as a Python notebook](https://github.com/preethampy/questions/blob/master/School%20marks%20pred.ipynb)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, median_absolute_error,accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv('student-mat.csv',sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('student-por.csv',sep=';')

df = [df,df2]
df = pd.concat(df)
df = pd.get_dummies(df)

X = df.drop('G3',axis=1)
y = df['G3']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = [int(round(i)) for i in y_pred]

accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

Comment: Hi, did you set normalize to true in your model ? And again look at the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for Scikit linear regression to check if there are other parameters that you might tweak to get better result. Otherwise you could also try other models. Best

Comment: Hi, In your code sample, why do you need this line [int(round(i)) for i in y_pred] ?  Could you compute the accuracy without that line of code  ?  Best

Comment: i used [int(round(i)) for i in y_pred] in particular because the predicted values are actually float type.So when i convert them to int dtype the accuracy is getting much lower because if the true value is 3 and the predicted value is 2.9 then converting predicted value 2.9 to int is making it 2.But rounding of it is giving 3 which makes True == Predicted values.And i converted rounded values to int again because when i rounded the values, at some point there are negative 0 values and to make it positive i did it.

Comment: As per your recommendations i tried setting normalize to true and the accuracy just decreased and n_jobs seems made no changes in output as well

Comment: HI, You do not need to convert it to int I think. To check how well  your model is doing . Just use the returned predicted value - because that gives you true performance.  Change the accuracy_score to mean_squared_error. Accuracy_score as explained [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) is used in classification task. Then try also  [linear model with regularisation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge).  -Best

Comment: this helped me a lot thank you and stay safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accuracy calculated on continous variables is not very useful. You can use the mean squared error instead, which is relevant for continuous output.

As for improving your model, you can try to use the different tools at your disposal to identify the most relevant features. I recommend `statsmodels` API (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html) to get a more in-depth analysis.

Comment: this seems to be working. MSE should be less or high for a good one ? i guess less right ?

Comment: You guessed right, please close this question by accepting the answer if you have solved your problem :)